# write and print producing different results

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse through a JSON file and get the first level value of a field into a different file.

The code I currently have is:

```
outfile = open('test.json','w')
with open('sample.json') as data:
    for line in data:
        j = json.loads(line)
        d = j["text"].encode('utf8')
        outfile.write( d )
        # print d
data.close()
outfile.close()
```

The `sample.json` file has 10000 lines, each line having at least one "text" field in different levels. I want only the first level "text" field.
The weird thing is, when I use `outfile.write( d )` I get 545 lines in my `test.json` file with some of them being blank lines, but when I use `print d` I get 10544 lines where none of them are blank.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: are you sure that the ````for```` loop isn't indented?

Comment: if you want help paste the contents of test.json somewhere ... as it is no one can reproduce your problem so no one knows how to fix it ... that said print adds a new line that write does not add ... but that does not account for the discrepency ... your terminal encoding is probably different causing different lengths

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the discrepancy that you see is likely caused by the fact that `print` appends a newline to it's output and `File.write()` does not. change

```
outfile.write( d )
```

To

```
outfile.write( "%s\n" % d )
```

Or

```
outfile.write( d + "\n" )
```

And the number of lines should match up.

As for the blank lines... without seeing your text I can only speculate but here goes:

Given that `File.write()` doesn't add new lines and you are getting a line with 545 lines, `d` must contain 544 `"\n"` characters. If these newline characters fall at the end of the strings (I think they do) then you'd end up with something like this:

```
>>> d = "foobar\n"
>>> print d
foobar

>>>
```

So that accounts for your blank lines. plus of course you have the `"\n"` appended to the string by print. So 10000 lines == 10000 newlines plus the 544 new lines that I assume are in the strings already..

```
>>> 10000 + 544
10544
```

Now for the 545 lines in the file.. so if there were no new lines in the strings we'd expect one line of text. 544 `"\n"` plus the line we started on (1)

```
>>> 544 + 1
545
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to replicate the `print`ed output the pythonic way is to use the `'a'` flag when you `open()` the file like so:

```
outfile = open('test.json','a')
```

If you want to escape the newline characters you should use:

```
d = d.replace("\n", "\\n")
d = d.replace("\r", "\\r") # for Windows \r characters
```

before `d` is outputted or written to a file

Comment: I did manage to get the `write` and `print` to output the same number of lines. And you are correct, the lines that produce the problem have `\n` in their `"text"` field. How can I ignore these escape characters in between the text?

Comment: @user3666471 ````"\n"```` is not an escaped character, it is an **unescaped** newline character. If you want it to appear literally as ````'\n'```` you should output the result of ````d.replace("\n", "\\n")````. Edited the answer

Comment: It's working now, thanks! I has to repeat the `replace` for `\r` as well for some lines.

Comment: @user3666471 indeed I'd forgotten about Window's ````"\r"````. I've updated the answer. Good catch.